# Having trouble with connecting SQLite in host Java

Tags: java, database, sqlite, jdbc, host

I'm trying to connect my SQLite database which i made with firefox plugin.It's including some table contents .  I uploaded it to our online host. I 'm trying to write this program for 4 of my friend. So we need to connect this database file. But i cant show the route to program. I know host's IP,password etc etc. I need just connect the host. This is how i'm trying to connect database.

PS: In this code which i will give below this PS, i'm just connecting to localhost. But i need to connect a host(IP) For example Connect to XXX.XX.XX(just random ip) and locate it sqlite file under C:

PS2:Host including a password, should everyone need this ?

PS3:I'm working with netbeans.

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class javaconnect {



    Connection conn=null;
    public static Connection ConnecrDb(){

    try{
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    Connection conn =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\XX.sqlite");

    return conn;
    }catch (Exception e){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
       return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not handle remote databases very well. According to their [Appropriate Uses For SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) page, "... Another way to look at SQLite is this: SQLite is not designed to replace Oracle. It is designed to replace fopen()." When you connect to an SQLite DB, you can only do it if you have direct access to the database file. If the file is shared on a remote drive, you can probably use `jdbc:sqlite:\\hostname\XX.sqlite` as your connection string, but only if you can see the file that way in Windows explorer.

On the other hand, you may want to try to install a database that intentionally allows remote connections. Apache Derby is a good one with a small footprint. It is written in Java and has a very nice and easy to use JDBC driver. Derby is available at http://db.apache.org/derby/.